# Identify graphic novel by its description: a low level invisible demon who can't touch his victim

Tags: story-identification

I read this fully illustrated graphic novel back AROUND 1999, it was written in English. The story takes place (I think entirely) within a man's house in which he lives. The house is also inhabited by a low ranking demon from Hell who has been commanded by Satan to torment this fellow.

The demon is bound by a rule in which he can't touch his victim directly, so he messes with his stuff instead, including killing the man's cat. I think the demon's job was to torment this fellow until he was driven mad, or perhaps to suicide, that his soul could be claimed by the devil.

The man comes close to breaking, but eventually deduces the demon's existence, and eventually tricks him into being touched which results in the demon becoming the man's unwilling servant.

There's a very memorable scene (which looked like one of the full page artworks from Spawn, although I don't think it was a MacFarlane story) where the little demon is reporting back to hell, and either Satan or one of his lieutenants is depicted enormous and menacing.

I think the man may have had a daughter too, but I can't remember what happened to her in the story. I think by the end she had left (or possibly died; how shocking that I can't remember such an important detail!)

I am aware that my post is VERY similar to this other user's post, but I assure you it is a different book. (The one in the link appears to be a novel with a very similar concept but a different plot line, whereas the one I read was a graphic novel): 
[Man has invisible demon following him that turns visible when eating people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161053/man-has-invisible-demon-following-him-that-turns-visible-when-eating-people?newreg=cc625491bc0f418480a6f04bf560ac53)

Literary sleuths, I will be supremely impressed if you can identify this one based on this exceedingly limited information. I read the book at a friend's house and noted it was a library book and figured "cool, I can get this out any time I want". Well it's been seventeen bloody years and it has proved *devilishly* tricky to identify, so I am now turning to the experts.

But that's an additional clue: it should still be in the Auckland Libraries catalogue.

Comment: Have you asked your friend what graphic novel he got out from the library?

Comment: Elementary :) His mother got it out of the library, and the friend has no memory of her doing so. She died a couple of years after I read it.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217704/story-about-a-demon-trying-to-make-a-man-insane (about the original short story)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["The Yattering and Jack", by Clive Barker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_Blood#Volume_One)
(Originally a short story in vol 1 of Barker's "Books of Blood" - I hadn't known about the graphic novel version but it's right at the top of the search results if you Google it)

> The Yattering subjects him to increasingly severe torments, including killing his cats and terrorising his family, but these efforts all fail. Eventually Jack tricks it into violating its orders, allowing Jack to take advantage of a loophole and make the Yattering his slave.